# exception in boost:interprocess, shared memory object deletion

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

there is a simple piece of code which I moved to main function of sample app to avoid the affecting of any other application parts:

```
    namespace bi = boost:interprocess;

    bi::shared_memory_object::remove("shm");
    bi::named_mutex::remove("mtx");
    bi::named_condition::remove("cnd");
```

just first line raise an exception in internal boost interprocess code:
in windows_intermodule_singleton.hpp, 118 (v 1.60.0)
bolded line is where it's happening.
Win64, VC v19, Windows 10

```
     ...
     caster.addr = m;
     BOOST_ASSERT((caster.addr_uint64 & boost::uint64_t(3)) == 0);
     max_count = boost::uint32_t(caster.addr_uint64 >> 32);
     **initial_count = boost::uint32_t(caster.addr_uint64);**
     initial_count = initial_count/4;
     //Make sure top two bits are zero
     BOOST_ASSERT((max_count & boost::uint32_t(0xC0000000)) == 0);
     //Set quasi-top bit
     max_count |= boost::uint32_t(0x40000000);
     ...
```

ANy idea why this happens? can this be related with x64 memory model?

Answer (score 0):

it was not an exception, my inattention ,
compiled with all /RTC compiler settings and this place looks like potential data loss (?) 8 bytes to 4.
windbg reports: _RTC_Check_8_to_4